# How do I hide an input element based on toggle?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I come from an MVC background so I'm relatively new to Angular.  I have a toggle slider that I want to use to show/hide another input field below it.  Check toggle, show field. Uncheck toggle, hide field.  I'm having issue with the anuglar materials underline and placehohlder text not hiding.  Or is there a better way of handling this, maybe presenting it in a different/better way?  Thanks for your time.

```
<div fxLayout="column">
  <div fxLayout="column">
    <span class="mb-8">Show Preposition</span>
    <mat-slide-toggle matInput name="prepositionCheckbox" formControlName="prepositionCheckbox" (click)="togglePreposition()"></mat-slide-toggle>
  </div>
  <mat-form-field fxFlex="22.5">
    <input [hidden]="!isPrepositionChecked" matInput name="preposition" formControlName="preposition" placeholder="Preposition For Location">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Hidden:

[image]

Shown:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why dont you hide mat-form-field?

```
  <mat-form-field fxFlex="22.5"  [hidden]="!isPrepositionChecked" >
     <input matInput name="preposition" formControlName="preposition" placeholder="Preposition For Location">
   </mat-form-field>
```

Or try *ngIf

```
  <mat-form-field fxFlex="22.5"  *ngIf="!isPrepositionChecked" >
     <input matInput name="preposition" formControlName="preposition" placeholder="Preposition For Location">
   </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: If I hide the mat form field, will it still post when i try to save?

Comment: Good question. Just try and see

Comment: Not sure if this works on the post, but it put me in the right direction to get this working as expected per my question.  Thanks